# necesito crear un programa para crear un mapa de puntos (PCL) para kineckt

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

quien puede guiarme en como hacer un mapa de puntos con kinect de 360 grados

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60423/necesito-crear-un-programa-para-crear-un-mapa-de-puntos-(pcl)-para-kineckt/) by [SEBASSALSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/4655/sebassalsa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

necesito crear un mapa de puntos en 360 grados si algien pudiera guiarme se lo agradeceria

---

Originally posted by [SEBASSALSA](https://answers.ros.org/users/4655/sebassalsa/) with karma: 16 on 2013-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) on 2013-04-11**:
Deberías complementar la pregunta en vez de escribir una respuesta... Has revisado la información sobre kinect  en http://www.ros.org/wiki/kinect?